# "Android library projects cannot be launched"?

Tags: android

Now I am totally confused by this error message: **Android library projects cannot be launched.**

I carefully checked the build path and library, everything seems "OK", and there is no error on Problems view, however, when I tried to run my application as an Android project, it failed and showed that message.

Any explanation for why it's happening is appreciated!

Answer (score 226, accepted):

From Android's Developer Documentation on Managing Projects from Eclipse with ADT:

[Setting up a Library Project](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject)

> Next, set the project's Properties to indicate that it is a library project:
>
> 1. In the **Package Explorer**, right-click the library project and select **Properties**.
> 2. In the **Properties** window, select the "Android" properties group at left and locate the **Library** properties at right.
> 3. Select the "is Library" checkbox and click **Apply**.
> 4. Click **OK** to close the *Properties* window.

So, open your project properties, un-select the "Is Library" checkbox, and click **Apply** to make your project a normal Android project (not a library project).

Comment: #winning - Perhaps the Eclipse interface is to blame here a little.  Maybe it should read, "Is Library: bool" divider "Libraries:" and then the list of linked libraries, since "Is Library" applies to the current project.  It confused me.

Comment: @TimothyLeeRussell yes, you are very correct, there needs to be a divider there for sure..

Comment: @TimothyLeeRussell, Eclipse is one of the [worst IDE](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/05/01.html) ever

Comment: @Pacerier Hyperbole aside, is that the "worst IDE" link you intended?  It doesn't seem to be about Eclipse.  I'm using IntelliJ for Android-only projects now.  My experience with it has been better than Eclipse although it has its issues as well.

Comment: @TimothyLeeRussell, Yes, the link is about Eclipse being over-engineered. Btw, do you encounter bugs? I'm thinking of switching to IntelliJ, but the quote from https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html *"Android Studio is currently in beta. Some features are not yet implemented and you may encounter bugs"* is stopping me from doing so. I'd really hate dealing with bugs that are not by me.

Comment: @Pacerier Ok, I get what you were saying with the link now.  I haven't used Android Studio.  I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.5 Community Edition. It has been significantly better than Eclipse and it integrates with the Android SDK just fine.

Comment: @TimothyLeeRussell, What do you mean by integrate with Android SDK just fine? Isn't the integration done via Android Studio?

Comment: @Pacerier I installed IntelliJ Community Edition and then installed the standalone Android SDK.  Then in IntelliJ, I pointed it at the Android sdk.

Comment: After selecting the checkbox still the same error is showing... Is there any other option

Answer (score 27):

Through the this steps you can .

1. In **Eclipse** , **Right Click** on **Project** from **Package Explorer**.
2. Select **Properties**,.
3. Select **Android** from **Properties** pop up window,
4. See "**Is Library**" check box,
5. If it is **checked** then **Unchecked** "Is Library" check box.
6. Click **Apply** and than **OK**.

Answer (score 10):

With Me I had the library ticked under Eclipse>Project Properties>Android what I just did was uncheck the ticked library.

Comment: I need to do the same to get the emulator to run, but it doesn't launch and I can't find it under the applications menu.

Answer (score 4):

It says “Android library projects cannot be launched” because Android library projects cannot be launched. That simple. You cannot run a library. If you want to test a library, create an Android project that uses the library, and execute it.

Comment: hi der.. Ijust changed the library .then changed back to default settings. first i got 'Can not find .apk file' when i tried to run the application. thanks

Comment: In Eclipse *Project -> Clean...*

Comment: "You cannot run a library". Except the library has everything needed to be run. You can even make it a library, add it to a project, and make it not a library again!

Comment: So you are saying the same thing than I do :P

Answer (score 3):

In Eclipse Project -> Clean 
Modify project.properties like this :

```
target=android-10
android.library.reference.1=F:/svn/WiEngine_library
```

Answer (score 0):

Through the following  steps you can do it .

In Eclipse window , Right Click on your Project from Package Explorer.
1. Select Properties,
2. Select Android from Properties,
3. Check "Is Library" check box,
4. If it is checked then Unchecked "Is Library" check box.
5. Click Apply and than OK.

Answer (score 0):

right-click in your project and select Properties. In the Properties window -> "Android" -> uncheck the option "is Library" and apply -> Click "ok" to close the properties window.

This is the best answer to solve the problem