# Android library projects cannot be launched

Tags: android, api, sdk

i've been trying to run a project but there's a pop up window that says **"Android library projects cannot be launched."**

Now, my project needs API 7 and i've already installed it in Android SDK Manager. 
In Properties -> Android -> Target build, i choose Android 4.1.2. I also added these lines to the Android Manifest:
 `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"
             android:targetSdkVersion="7"
             android:maxSdkVersion="16"/>`

yet, when i run my project, the same pop up message shows.
Anyone, please help me. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282552/android-library-projects-cannot-be-launched You can't launch library projects, so check if this project is a library.

Comment: i've already checked the Is Library yet i can't run

Comment: I meant check as in verify. You can't run library projects. Is that project supposed to be run?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your project surely is configured as "library" thats why you get the message : **"Android library projects cannot be launched."**

right-click in your project and select Properties.
In the Properties window -> "Android" -> uncheck the option "is Library" and apply -> Click "ok" to close the properties window.

Comment: I am so curious about why this error occur? I copy one package files to another project and the error shows up. The copied project works well, but the other doesn't. Why?

Comment: Hi Stallman, probably you are copying a project.properties file that contains the property: android.library=true

Answer (score 0):

the naive and somewhat literal interpretation of the message would be that your project IS a library project; and indeed, they cannot be launched, only embedded in some main project.

Did you double check that your project is NOT a library project? There used to be a checkbox in the "create new android project" wizard...