# Is there anyway I can make an application on android version 2.1 that has navigation drawer

Tags: android

I've downloaded a sample application of a Navigation drawer from developer.android.com
and I want it to be installed on minimum versions like android 2.1.. Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sure, use this library:
https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

**Simple Example**

```
public class SlidingExample extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTitle(R.string.attach);
        // set the content view
        setContentView(R.layout.content);
        // configure the SlidingMenu
        SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
        menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
        menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
        menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
        menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
        menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
        menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
        menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
        menu.setMenu(R.layout.menu);
    }

}
```

Comment: the ExampleListActivity folder contain lots of error please help! Thank you so much!

Comment: No it doesn't I think errors are caused by incorrectly linked libraries. Anyway To help I need to know what this errors are.

Comment: here it is..Description Resource Path Location Type
Project 'ExampleListActivity' is missing required Java project: 'SlidingExample' ExampleListActivity  Build path Build Path Problem... Here are my errors Sir @Malachiasz

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'homeAsUpIndicator'. styles.xml /ExampleListActivity/res/values line 5 Android AAPT Problem

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar'. styles.xml /ExampleListActivity/res/values line 4 Android AAPT Problem
@Malachiasz

Comment: Sir @Malachiasz I've already attached the actionbar sherlock (actionbarsherlock.com/usage.html) as what I've read here. And then when I tried to run the library project that I downloaded from github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu... An error appeared saying Android library projects cannot be launched

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282552/android-library-projects-cannot-be-launched